# How to get browser Idle time in NodeJS script?

Tags: node.js

I'm planning to create simple users browser tracking system, where I want to track whether user is idle for certain time or not. I thought NodeJS would be the ideal choice.

Found certain NodeJS modules as well. But the problem is that all of them are using document. But in my case there is not document object is available, as I'm using pure NodeJS where there is no browser interaction is possible as I want to tack browser inactivity in background.

I tried below NPM Module.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/away

Which gives below error.

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/d/Projects/PHPProjects/ets/node_modules/away/index.js:16:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/d/Projects/PHPProjects/ets/index.js:16:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
```

**Here is my implementation**

```
// HTTP Module
var http = require('http');

// OS Utility Module
var os = require('os-utils');

// Native OS object
var osNative = require('os');

// MySQL Connection Setup
var mysql = require('mysql');

// Create server
var server = http.createServer(function() {});

var away = require('away');

// detect users who are idle for 10 seconds
var timer = away(5000);

timer.on('idle', function() {
    console.log('user is idle');
});
timer.on('active', function() {
    console.log('user is active');
});
```

Comment: You can't detect browser idle time on the server side unless you're doing something on the client side that indicates activity (hence lack thereof). You can send info back in any number of ways.

Comment: @DaveNewton You're correct, All computers I want to monitor are in my control. I can install and run NodeJS script on those terminals. Then is that possible?

Comment: You want to monitor browser time regardless of which sites the users are on? That will be quite a bit trickier, and it depends on what you mean by "using the browser", e.g., do you want to monitor if a user is scrolling a third-party website (like reading an article)? Without knowing what your requirements are this question is impossible to answer. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to track users activity (browsed urls) and keep a log for those urls to monitor my team browsing activity.

Comment: Want to trace browser urls in background when they are using browser.

Comment: Seems like it'd be *hugely* easier to do this via your corporate network. If you feel obligated to spy on your network's users, do it at the infrastructural level. There's not going to be any simple way to do this across all browsers.